# Python Tkinter Grid doesn't work properly

Tags: python, tkinter, grid

I am trying to arrange a logo at the top and widgets in 3 part below the logo. I tried to set the ratio of those 3 part to be same, but when I run the code below, the ratio isn't same.

My code is

```
import tkinter as tk

window = tk.Tk()
window.title("My Program")
window.geometry("700x400")

logo = tk.Label(window, text="Logo")
logo.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=3, sticky="nw", padx=10, pady=10)

window.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
window.columnconfigure(1, weight=1)
window.columnconfigure(2, weight=1)

window.rowconfigure(1, weight=1)
window.rowconfigure(2, weight=1)
window.rowconfigure(3, weight=1)

button1 = tk.Button(window, text="Button 1")
button1.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky="nsew", padx=10, pady=10)

button2 = tk.Button(window, text="Button 2")
button2.grid(row=2, column=0, sticky="nsew", padx=10, pady=10)

button3 = tk.Button(window, text="Button 3")
button3.grid(row=3, column=0, sticky="nsew", padx=10, pady=10)

big_label = tk.Label(window, text="Big Label")
big_label.grid(row=1, column=1, rowspan=3, sticky="nsew", padx=10, pady=10)

button4 = tk.Button(window, text="Button 4")
button4.grid(row=1, column=2, sticky="nsew", padx=10, pady=10)

button5 = tk.Button(window, text="Button 5")
button5.grid(row=2, column=2, sticky="nsew", padx=10, pady=10)

entry = tk.Entry(window)
entry.grid(row=3, column=2, sticky="nsew", padx=10, pady=10)

window.mainloop()
```

When I run the code, the result is below
[image]

As you can see, the column 2 is thicker than others. How should I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want all the columns have same size, you need to set `uniform=1` in all `.columnconfigure(...)` as well:

```py
window.columnconfigure(0, weight=1, uniform=1)
window.columnconfigure(1, weight=1, uniform=1)
window.columnconfigure(2, weight=1, uniform=1)
```

Same for all `.rowconfigure(...)`.

Result:

[image]

Comment: Worked! Thank you so much. But why does the row configure codes work without uniform=1, while column configure codes need it?

Comment: @josephyumss It may be because those widgets have around the same height.

Answer (score 0):

There are arguments for tkinter widgets like width and height. Here is an example:

```
button = tk.Button(window, width=20)
```

For the grid you have to use grid column configure and set it to different weights.

```
window.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
```

Would be the same for configuring the row.

Comment: I have those in my code. I've set the weight to be 1 for every column.

Answer (score -1):

To achieve equal ratios for the three parts below the logo in your Tkinter code, you can use the weight parameter in the grid_rowconfigure() function. Here's an updated version of your code with modifications to achieve equal ratios:

```
import tkinter as tk
window = tk.Tk()
window.title("My Program")
window.geometry("700x400")

logo = tk.Label(window, text="Logo")
logo.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=3, sticky="nw", padx=10, 
pady=10)

window.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
window.columnconfigure(1, weight=1)
window.columnconfigure(2, weight=1)

window.rowconfigure(1, weight=1)
window.rowconfigure(2, weight=1)
window.rowconfigure(3, weight=1)

button1 = tk.Button(window, text="Button 1")
button1.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky="nsew", padx=10, pady=10)

button2 = tk.Button(window, text="Button 2")
button2.grid(row=2, column=0, sticky="nsew", padx=10, pady=10)

button3 = tk.Button(window, text="Button 3")
button3.grid(row=3, column=0, sticky="nsew", padx=10, pady=10)

big_label = tk.Label(window, text="Big Label")
big_label.grid(row=1, column=1, rowspan=3, sticky="nsew", 
padx=10, pady=10)

button4 = tk.Button(window, text="Button 4")
button4.grid(row=1, column=2, sticky="nsew", padx=10, pady=10)

button5 = tk.Button(window, text="Button 5")
button5.grid(row=2, column=2, sticky="nsew", padx=10, pady=10)

# Add weight to the rows to achieve equal ratios
window.rowconfigure(0, weight=0)  # No weight for the logo row
window.rowconfigure(1, weight=1)
window.rowconfigure(2, weight=1)
window.rowconfigure(3, weight=1)

window.mainloop()
```